# Wireless doesn't work after suspend on a Centrino Wireless-N 130 on a Samsung NC110-A01

Tags: wireless, samsung, intel-wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 on a new Samsung NC110-AO1. Whenever I resume a session after being suspended, my wireless will connect to the network, but I will not be able to view any websites. No data is being downloaded.

A wired connection works fine.

This problem occurs when on battery power, which is annoying as you don't buy a netbook to keep it plugged in all the time.

There is no problem with the wireless with Windows 7 on the same machine.

The problem disappears if I reboot, but this isn't a solution as it will come back and soon as I suspend/resume a session.

I will not have access to the router on most connections I will be using, so anything involving turning it off and on is out of the question.

**How can I go about solving this problem? Any help will be much appreciated.**

**This is the output of lshw -C network**

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 130
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 34
   serial: dc:a9:71:8d:91:c2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=3.0.0-16-generic firmware=17.168.5.1 build 33993 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:47 memory:f0100000-f0101fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 05
   serial: e8:11:32:de:fb:76
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:44 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f050c000-f050cfff memory:f0508000-f050bfff
```

**And here is the output of lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hrtimer            12648  1 
bnep                   17923  2 
rfcomm                 38408  8 
parport_pc             32114  0 
ppdev                  12849  0 
joydev                 17393  0 
arc4                   12473  2 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   254125  1 
binfmt_misc            17292  1 
samsung_backlight      13487  0 
uvcvideo               67271  0 
videodev               85626  1 uvcvideo
snd_hda_intel          24262  2 
snd_hda_codec          91859  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80435  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
btusb                  18160  2 
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
bluetooth             148839  23 bnep,rfcomm,btusb
psmouse                73673  0 
serio_raw              12990  0 
snd_rawmidi            25241  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51567  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28932  3 snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
iwlagn                273980  0 
mac80211              393421  1 iwlagn
i915                  509519  2 
snd                    55902  14                 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_t                imer,snd_seq_device
drm_kms_helper         32889  1 i915
drm                   192194  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
cfg80211              172427  2 iwlagn,mac80211
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
soundcore              12600  1 snd
video                  18908  1 i915
snd_page_alloc         14115  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
ahci                   21634  2 
libahci                25727  1 ahci
r8169                  43104  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this method will help:

1. Find your wireless card it this list:
   lspci
2. Find out what driver your card using now:
   lsmod
3. Try to find driver for this card (for example: for my D-Link DW-525 there was Ralink driver)
4. Install original driver.
5. Blacklist old default driver.

I've done this and now it's OK.

Comment: How exactly can I blacklist the driver? The command "blacklist" doesn't do anything, and when I try to edit the blacklist files in /etc/modprobe.d I am told I do not have permission to, despite being Administrator

Answer (score 0):

To update blacklist.conf, you need root authority. For example,

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

make your edit, and save the file.

Alternatively, you could use

```
sudo -e /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

There are many ways to do it, but however you do it, it requires root authority.

Comment: I edited your answer, in general nano is easier for new user (although do not get me wrong, I am a vim fanboi). If you are going to suggest using vi, best to include some direction of how to save edits (:wq)