# Hardware wireless switch has no effect after suspend and 13.10 upgrade

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, hardware, suspend

This seems to be a fairly chronic problem, as shown by the following questions:

[How do I fix a "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139036/how-do-i-fix-a-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-error)

[Wireless disabled by hardware switch on an Asus X550V](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351594/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch)

["Wireless disabled by hardware switch" after suspend and other hardware buttons ineffective - how can I solve this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240929/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch-after-suspend-and-other-hardware-buttons)

but no good solutions have been found!

Wireless works fine after a reboot, but after a suspend the hardware switch (for my laptop this is `f12`) has no effect on the wireless, it is just permanently off, and shows that it is with a red LED. All

My `rfkill list all` reads:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: yes
```

Any combination with `rfkill <un>block wifi` doesn't work, although *one time* first `block`ing then `unblock`ing actually turned it on again.

`sudo lshw -C network` reads:

```
    *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 78:e4:00:65:2e:3f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.11.0-12-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:90100000-9010ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: c8:0a:a9:89:b4:30
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90010000-90010fff memory:90000000-9000ffff memory:90020000-9002ffff
```

Also, adding a `/etc/pm/sleep.d/brcm.sh` file as recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240929/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch-after-suspend-and-other-hardware-buttons) simply prevents the laptop from suspending **at all**, which of course is no good.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107899/wireless-doesnt-work-after-suspend-on-a-centrino-wireless-n-130-on-a-samsung-nc) has an answer urging to install the original driver, but it wasn't an "accepted answer" so I'd rather not take a chance on it. Also I'll admit I'm a bit lost on that and would like help doing so with the specific information I've given.

`xev` shows that no internal event is triggered for my wireless switch (`f12`), but other function keys also acting as hardware switches work fine. **Edit** this doesn't matter, since `xev` shows no event even when the switch is properly working. I'm considering removing this paragraph....

I would be happy to provide more information, so long as you're willing to help me find it for you! This is a very annoying bug.

I have a `Compaq Presario CQ62`.

**Edit**. I just tried to reload bios defaults (or something) as shown by [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB2-oaePlKc). Didn't work.

**Edit**. I tried the contents of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153092/cant-find-intel-wireless-n-1000-after-waking-from-sleep?rq=1), and it didn't work.

**Edit**. Output of `lspci | grep Network`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

**Edit**. Pastebins of more lengthy outputs are given below in the comments.

**Edit**. I don't know if I'm right, but I found this line in `dmesg`:

```
[    0.198949] acpi PNP0A08:00: ACPI _OSC support notification failed, disabling PCIe ASPM
```

which seems like it might be something, since it refers to `PCI`.... I'm a noob who's trying my best!

**Edit**. This? From `dmesg`? It has the name `ath` and `phy0` which relates to the driver and one of the network interfaces (as far as I know).

```
[  106.592792] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
```

**Edit**. This morning, I had had the laptop suspended all night, and then when I tried to awake it, it simply wouldn't. It would try, and then it would sleep again (I guess it felt a little bit like me! `</badjoke>`). Is it possible these problems are related?

Comment: Will the Ubuntu developers solve this problem in the near future do you think?

Comment: What is the result of: sudo rfkill unblock 0? How about: sudo rfkill unblock 1?

Comment: Tried it, no effect I'm afraid :/

Comment: How about: sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi && sudo rfkill unblock all? If it helps, we can make it permanent.

Comment: No effect :/ This is a super annoying bug!!

Comment: Maybe something with `rmmod`? I'm seeing answers with that, but I'm not sure what inputs to give it.

Comment: Interesting. We see nothing whatever that indicates that your wireless is blocked. In fact, we see: "wlan0: associated" Please pastebin: iwconfig and nm-tool.

Comment: I think I've been making the mistake of posting some outputs when I AM successfully connected, since I can't post the information when I'm not! I'm at a second computer right now, and so I'll double check all of the info I've given to make sure it's relevant, and I'll get you `iwconfig` and `nm-tool`.

Comment: An [updated lsmod](http://pastebin.com/QGeTSfXU), an [updated dmesg](http://pastebin.com/sHFWbpg4), and here's [iwconfig](http://pastebin.com/c01UAFGn) (I manually added the last two lines, since my shell sent them to stdout rather than being redirected into the file), and [nm-tool](http://pastebin.com/QtQHaKkW). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LITERALLY, an update today took care of the problem. Sorry I can't be more helpful to any future sufferers of this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a new machine but messed my network setting up.

1. I installed gksu
2. I ran

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces
   ```
3. Edit the file with:

   ```
   # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
   # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

   # The loopback network interface
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   # This is a list of hotpluggable network interfaces.
   # They will be activated automatically by the hotplug subsystem.
   # auto eth1

   # iface eth1 inet dhcp
   ```

   then just save it.
4. Just to make sure everything is ok

   please check your `dhcpd.conf` file found in `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` to make sure

   ```
   option domain-name "example.org";
   option domain-name-server ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

   default-lease-time 600;
   max-lease-time 7200;
   ```

   do not have # before them.
5. Now restart your system and I hope it works just like mine did.

Comment: I would upvote you, since it seems this is a good answer, but an update solved it!