# Update to 13.10: blank screen and repeated suspend on resume from suspend

Tags: suspend

On my Asus x201e, after updating from 13.04 to 13.10, intermittently when awaking from suspend, my screen will blink to a black screen a few times, offer a lock screen, and then go back to suspend unexpectedly (during this it is possible to quickly login to the desktop before the system suspends again). This will repeat each time I subsequently awake it from suspend. Only a restart will escape the suspend loop.

The problem only occurs when suspending by closing lid, not by manual (pm-suspend) or menu suspend. Opening the lid after a manual or menu-initiated suspend works as expected.

When an external monitor is attached, the black screen and second lock screen still appear twice upon wake, but the system does not fall back into suspend (though networking is disabled and [needs to be restarted](https://askubuntu.com/a/365824/208026)).

This issue arose in tandem with the [already raised issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365441/13-10-suspend-kills-wifi) regarding networking not restarting on wake from suspend, though appears to be distinct from that issue and persists after a [fix is applied for the networking issue](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182128&p=12830153#post12830153).

This issue only occurs on waking from suspend, never upon booting. And only on the second suspend cycle after reboot.

This question duplicates the second, unanswered question included in [this closed question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361991/suspend-problems-in-13-10) and seems to correspond with this [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1243647).

Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: This happens when suspending/after resuming, not after booting.

Comment: That this issue occurs on resuming and not after booting has been emphasized in the original post.

Comment: Which graphics drivers are you using?

Comment: It's just a Celeron with Intel Sandybridge Mobile graphics, using open source drivers.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, with a Lenovo X201T.

Comment: Can the reason that this was marked as off-topic be clarified? This question does not concern a development version of Ubuntu.