# Ubuntu 13.10 - Wifi not re-connecting after suspend

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I upgraded the other day from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 on my ZaReason laptop, and the WiFi doesn't reconnect after suspend.

In 13.04, pressing Fn+F2 turned network connections back on after suspend. The 'soft' wireless hardware switch.

But in 13.10, that doesn't work, and trying to enable networking in the networking menu doesn't work either. So I have to restart every time.

Any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried turning wireless off before suspending?

Comment: @guntbert err... that got closed because it's a bug.

Comment: @braiam indeed - this is about the same bug, but pointing people to the question with more info is still good, don't you think?

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/365441/13-10-suspend-kills-wifi-connection

Answer (score 8):

The [answer above](https://askubuntu.com/a/368732/208026) solves the problem in a one off fashion, but these steps solved the longterm issue for me:

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
```

Insert the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
thaw|resume)
nmcli nm sleep false
;;
*)
;;
esac
exit $?
```

And then save.

Solution found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182128&p=12830153#post12830153)

Answer (score 5):

**Workaround**:

<s>Try restarting the network manager to start wifi again:</s>

sudo service network-manager restart

***Update:***

https://askubuntu.com/a/362148/175489

Much better workaround:

```
sudo nmcli nm sleep false
```

Answer (score 2):

Please do:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

A new empty file will open. Add one line:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8192ce"
```

Of course, substitute your actual driver in place of rtl8192ce. Proofread, save and close gedit.
Reboot

If you do not know the name of your wireless driver run this command:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

it will tell you the device name for wireless and ethernet along with the driver being used for each.

Edit: This second method will most likely work if the first one does not:

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
```

Insert the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
thaw|resume)
nmcli nm sleep false
;;
*)
;;
esac
exit $?
Save
```

This answer was found [on the forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182128&p=12830153#post12830153)

Comment: It works, but I still have to press Fn+F2 after I enable networking for the WiFi to come on. That's fine though, I've had to do that with 13.04 as well.