# Problems with 5GHz wifi in Kubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, kubuntu, network-manager, suspend

NetworkManager works just fine as long as I'm connected to a 2.4GHz access point. I can suspend, resume, etc and it always finds my proper network and reconnects. The problem begins when I select a 5GHz wifi network. I can see and connect to the network and it functions just fine, but when I suspend/resume and occasionally when I reboot none of the 5GHz networks show up in the network list. I have to completely disable wireless networking for several seconds, then re-enable it to find my access point.

Comment: have you seen this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/365441/13-10-suspend-kills-wifi