# Wifi Dies and doesnt Reconnect after Suspend Option (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: wireless

Before I get started, yes I have googled this problem LOL, this one seems to be the one that works:
[13.10 suspend kills wifi connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365441/13-10-suspend-kills-wifi-connection)

The code that helps alot of people is this:

[CODE]sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

Insert the following lines:
  #!/bin/bash case "$1" in thaw|resume) nmcli nm sleep false ;; *) ;; esac exit $? [/CODE]

And then you save the gedit file.

When I do that I get this error:

CODE: Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(gedit:24243): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

[/CODE]

Anyone know how to get out of this problem? I have to always unplug my router its annoying because I need Ubuntu for school.

Thanks in advance

I have a HP Pavilion g6.

Answer (score 0):

Gedit gives me similar errors as well. I don't know why, but the program still works well for me, and it has worked for you as well.

But I understand if the errors concern you; you can try using the *nano* text editor instead of gedit. It is command line-based. Just replace *gedit* with *nano* when you are entering a command. To save, use Ctrl+O, and to exit, Ctrl+X. If you made changes to a file without saving, using Ctrl+X will give a prompt at which you can decide to save your changes, go back, or discard your changes.

Also, be sure to make your discussion title more relevant to the issue you're experiencing so as to not mislead anyone willing to provide you with solutions, out of respect to the forum, its users, and its visitors. Further, a more specific title will more likely attract those who have experienced your issue to help you or even those who have not experienced it but know that they can help.

Comment: I'm not sure why but now the sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh, is not being recognized in terminal the actual command it says chmod command not found

Comment: i dont know how to save the code on nano

Comment: You can save by holding the Control (Ctrl) key and pressing the letter, O. To exit the nano editor, hold the Ctrl key and press the "X" key. If you haven't saved, though, and you exit nano, you will be given a chance to save. Bear in mind, too, that gedit still works well, and you can also check out the emacs editor. I haven't used it but its another popular editor.